# How to create matrix of distribution in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe in R.

```
ID         Date                  List             Type
P-10012    2020-04-15 12:13:15   ABC,ABD,BCD      TR1
P-10012    2020-04-15 12:13:15   ABC,ABD,BCD      RES
P-10012    2020-04-15 12:13:15   ABC,ABD,BCD      FTT
P-10013    2020-04-12 17:10:05                    TR1
P-10013    2020-04-12 17:10:05                    FTT
P-10013    2020-04-12 17:10:05                    ZXR
P-10014    2020-04-10 04:30:19   ABD,BCD          TR1
P-10014    2020-04-10 04:30:19   ABD,BCD          ZXR
P-10015    2020-04-10 14:13:15   ABC              
P-10016    2020-04-10 13:13:15   
P-10017    2020-03-18 10:13:15   ABC,ABD,BCD      TR1



dput(df)
df <- structure(list(ID = c("P-10012", "P-10012", 
"P-10012", "P-10013", "P-10013", "P-10013", 
"P-10014", "P-10014", "P-10015", "P-10016", 
"P-10017"), Date = c("2020-04-15 12:13:15", "2020-04-15 12:13:15", 
"2020-04-15 12:13:15", "2020-04-12 17:10:05", "2020-04-12 17:10:05", 
"2020-04-12 17:10:05", "2020-04-10 04:30:19", "2020-04-10 04:30:19", 
"2020-04-10 14:13:15", "2020-04-10 13:13:15", "2020-03-18 10:13:15"
), Type = c("TR1", "RES", "FTT", "TR1", "FTT", "ZXR", "TR1", "ZXR", NA, NA, "TR1"), List = c("ABC,ABD,BCD", "ABC,ABD,BCD", "ABC,ABD,BCD", 
"", "", "", "ABD,BCD", "ABD,BCD", "ABC", "", "ABC,ABD,BCD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

The structure of the dataframe is that it will always have the same `List` value for a particular `ID` in case if there are multiple row available for that particular `ID` because it has multiple different value in `Type`. If for a particular `ID` there is only 1 `Type` value then it will always have one row.

I need to create the following distribution for the month of `Apr-20` of `List` values as mentioned in the comma separated manner and `Type` values.

Where, the first 7 rows in my `Required Df` are distinct count of `ID` based on the condition (i.e whether `List` or `Type` are blank or not) and distribution across all unique `List` and `Type` value. For these 7 rows the `Distinct_Count` should be divided by `Total` to get `Percentage`. However, from 8th row and onward if the unique value is form `List` then it should be divided by total distinct count of `Non_Blank_List` and if the value is from `Type` then it should be divided by total distinct count of `Non_Blank_Type`.

In the following matrix, I just want to understand what is the distribution of unique values of `List` and `Type` distinctly and in combination with other values.

Please not that for the example purpose I have simplified the `List` and `Type` values in 3 and 4 unique values respectively but in my actual dataframe it is quite high and it varies from month to month so please don't hard code the values.

I have tried multiple approach but couldn't achieve the required output yet.

Required Df<-

```
APR-21           Distinct_Count    Percentage    ABC     ABD      BCD     TR1    RES    FTT     ZXR
Total_ID         5                 100.00%       2       2        2       3      1      2       2 
Blank_List       2                 40.00%        0       0        0       1      0      1       1
Blank_Type       2                 40.00%        1       0        0       0      0      0       0
Both_Blank       1                 20.00%        0       0        0       0      0      0       0
Non_Blank_List   3                 60.00%        2       2        2       2      1      1       1         
Non_Blank_Type   3                 60.00%        1       2        2       3      1      1       2
Both_Non_Blank   2                 40.00%        1       2        2       2      1      1       1
ABC              1                 33.33%        2       1        1       1      1      1       0
ABD              0                  0.00%        1       2        2       2      1      1       1
BCD              0                  0.00%        1       2        2       2      1      1       1
TR1              0                  0.00%        1       2        2       3      1      1       1 
RES              0                  0.00%        1       1        1       1      1      1       0    
FTT              0                  0.00%        1       1        1       2      1      2       1 
ZXR              0                  0.00%        0       1        1       1      0      1       2
```

Comment: @akrun- Updated the `dput`

Comment: Does an `ID` always have the same `Date` value?

Comment: @DanChaltiel - Yes, unique `ID` will have the same date.

Comment: Are you sure about the `Distinct_Count` beyond "Both_Non_Blank"? There is only one row with ABC on its own, the other columns seem to consider all rows that contain ABC with or without others.

Comment: @DanChaltiel - Yes, column 2 which is `Distinct_Count` gives the distinct count of particular given condition or values (i.e ABC, ABD etc.) available distinctly to a unique `ID`. Whereas, column beyond column 2 are count of combination along with the value mentioned in row.

Comment: The last row of input data has a March date, but it seems necessary to include it to get three ABC ID's, no?

Comment: @JonSpring - No, 3 came from as `ID` `P-10012`, `P-10014` and `P-10015` has ABC.

Comment: How do we know that P-10014 does?

Comment: @JonSpring - Ohhh, My bad. It doesn't.

Comment: @SophiaWilson Please take a look at my edited answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest challenge is that keys come in rows and columns.

I used 2 custom functions to count the occurrences:

- `getcount()`, which uses a condition argument (see [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) if you are not familiar with quosures), for your special conditional rows (TotalID, Blank_list, ...)
- `getcount2()`, which uses a simple character argument, for your cases rows (ABC, BCD, TR1...)

Both work mostly the same way. We calculate the count separately for all single cases and for the total, always grouping by `ID` and concatenate the results.

Here is the code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- structure(list(ID = c("P-10012", "P-10012", "P-10012", "P-10013", "P-10013", "P-10013", 
                            "P-10014", "P-10014", "P-10015", "P-10016", "P-10017"), 
                     Date = c("2020-04-15 12:13:15", "2020-04-15 12:13:15", "2020-04-15 12:13:15", 
                              "2020-04-12 17:10:05", "2020-04-12 17:10:05", "2020-04-12 17:10:05", 
                              "2020-04-10 04:30:19", "2020-04-10 04:30:19", "2020-04-10 14:13:15", 
                              "2020-04-10 13:13:15", "2020-03-18 10:13:15"), 
                     Type = c("TR1", "RES", "FTT", "TR1", "FTT", "ZXR", "TR1", "ZXR", NA, NA, "TR1"),
                     List = c("ABC,ABD,BCD", "ABC,ABD,BCD", "ABC,ABD,BCD", "", "", "", "ABD,BCD", 
                              "ABD,BCD", "ABC", "", "ABC,ABD,BCD")), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

#extract all the individual values from Type and List
cases = c(df$Type, str_split(df$List, ", ?", simplify=TRUE)) %>% unique() %>% 
  sort() %>% .[.!=""] %>% rlang::set_names()

#util function
is_blank = function(x) is.na(x) | x==""

#get count for summary rows (TotalID, Blank_list, ...)
getcount = function(cond){
  x = map_dbl(cases, ~df %>% 
                filter(month(Date)==4) %>%
                group_by(ID) %>% 
                summarise(rtn=any({{cond}} & (str_detect(Type, .x) | str_detect(List, .x)))) %>% 
                pull() %>% sum(na.rm=TRUE)
  )
  x_tot = df %>% 
    filter(month(Date)==4) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(rtn=any({{cond}})) %>% 
    pull() %>% sum(na.rm=TRUE)
  
  c(x_tot, x)
}

#get count for cases rows (ABC, BCD, TR1...)
getcount2 = function(key){
  x = map_dbl(cases, ~df %>% 
                filter(month(Date)==4) %>%
                group_by(ID) %>% 
                summarise(rtn=any(
                  (key %in% Type  | str_detect(List, key)) &
                    (str_detect(Type, .x ) | str_detect(List, .x ))
                )) %>% 
                pull() %>% sum(na.rm=TRUE)
  )
  x_tot = df %>% 
    filter(month(Date)==4) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(rtn=any(List==key)) %>% 
    pull() %>% sum(na.rm=TRUE)
  
  c(tot=x_tot, x)
}


#here we go!
tibble(x=c("Distinct_Count", cases)) %>% 
  mutate(
    Total_ID=getcount(TRUE),
    Blank_List=getcount(is_blank(List)),
    Blank_Type=getcount(is_blank(Type)),
    Blank_Both=getcount(is_blank(List) & is_blank(Type)),
    Non_Blank_List=getcount(!is_blank(List)),
    Non_Blank_Type=getcount(!is_blank(Type)),
    Non_Blank_Both=getcount(!is_blank(List) & !is_blank(Type))
  ) %>% 
  bind_cols(map_dfc(cases, ~getcount2(.x))) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("x") %>% 
  t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(Percentage = scales::percent(Distinct_Count/max(Distinct_Count)), .after="Distinct_Count")
#>                Distinct_Count Percentage ABC ABD BCD FTT RES TR1 ZXR
#> Total_ID                    5       100%   2   2   2   2   1   3   2
#> Blank_List                  2        40%   0   0   0   1   0   1   1
#> Blank_Type                  2        40%   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
#> Blank_Both                  1        20%   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#> Non_Blank_List              3        60%   2   2   2   1   1   2   1
#> Non_Blank_Type              3        60%   1   2   2   2   1   3   2
#> Non_Blank_Both              2        40%   1   2   2   1   1   2   1
#> ABC                         1        20%   2   1   1   1   1   1   0
#> ABD                         0         0%   1   2   2   1   1   2   1
#> BCD                         0         0%   1   2   2   1   1   2   1
#> FTT                         0         0%   1   1   1   2   1   2   1
#> RES                         0         0%   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
#> TR1                         0         0%   1   2   2   2   1   3   2
#> ZXR                         0         0%   0   1   1   1   0   2   2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Note that there are several minor differences with your expected output, but I assume they are little mistakes from your complex example. For instance, ABC has Distinct_Count==1 so out of 5 it should not make 33%. Also, ZXR can be seen with TR1 twice (ID 13 and 14).